# Access and change html of divs with a given string ID in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, each

I am using the following code to access all the div which have a given string ID (those starting with the string "brand":

```
var tipo = "brand".
jQuery('div[id ^= "' + tipo + '"]').hide();
```

It works perfectly, and hide all the divs at once. But I would like to get a list (array) of all id's affected to change its .html(), but don't know how to achieve this. I have tried.

```
 jQuery('div[id ^= "' + tipo + '"]').each(
     alert(this.id);
 );
```

to show an alert for each ID found, but no success. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass anonymous function to [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method:

```
jQuery('div[id ^= "' + tipo + '"]').each(function() {
     alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get an array of the ids with

```
var ids = jQuery('div[id ^= "' + tipo + '"]').map(function(){
     return this.id;
}).get();
```

Note the use of the `function` keyword to create an anonymous function, which is called by `map` (it's called a callback).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 jQuery('div[id ^= "' + tipo + '"]').each(function(){
     alert( $(this).attr('id') );
 )};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a callback function as the argument.

```
jQuery('div[id^="' + tipo + '"]').each(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

```js
var tipo = "a";
jQuery('div[id^="' + tipo + '"]').each(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1"></div>
<div id="a2"></div>
<div id="a3"></div>
<div id="a4"></div>
```

---

For getting an array of ids use **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** method.

```
var ids = jQuery('div[id^="' + tipo + '"]').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

```js
var tipo = "a";
var ids = jQuery('div[id^="' + tipo + '"]').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();

console.log(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1"></div>
<div id="a2"></div>
<div id="a3"></div>
<div id="a4"></div>
```